# nodejs upgrade causing stack trace

Tags: node.js

I just upgraded to node v6. Everything is running fine, but I am getting the following stacktrace noting that something is being deprecated:

```
(node) v8::ObjectTemplate::Set() with non-primitive values is deprecated
(node) and will stop working in the next major release.

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0x18c48b3c9fa9 <JS Object>#0#
    1: .node [module.js:568] [pc=0x14a2e95935a4] (this=0x3e1b399e54e9 <an Object with map 0x31db83e17be1>#1#,module=0x1b9e891a8351 <a Module with map 0x31db83e181b9>#2#,filename=0x1b9e891a8319 <String[114]: /Users/alexanderray/WebstormProjects/skillx/node_modules/dtrace-provider/build/Release/DTraceProviderBindings.node>)
    2: load [module.js:456] [pc=0x14a2e9438e72] (this=0x1b9e891a8351 <a Module with map 0x31db83e181b9>#2#,filename=0x1b9e891a8319 <String[114]: /Users/alexanderray/WebstormProjects/skillx/node_modules/dtrace-provider/build/Release/DTraceProviderBindings.node>)
    3: tryModuleLoad(aka tryModuleLoad) [module.js:415] [pc=0x14a2e943899d] (this=0x18c48b304189 <undefined>,module=0x1b9e891a8351 <a Module with map 0x31db83e181b9>#2#,filename=0x1b9e891a8319 <String[114]: /Users/alexanderray/WebstormProjects/skillx/node_modules/dtrace-provider/build/Release/DTraceProviderBindings.nod 1: v8::Template::Set(v8::Local<v8::Name>, v8::Local<v8::Data>, v8::PropertyAttribute)
 2: node::DTraceProvider::Initialize(v8::Local<v8::Object>)
 3: node::DLOpen(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&)
 4: v8::internal::FunctionCallbackArguments::Call(void (*)(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&))
 5: v8::internal::MaybeHandle<v8::internal::Object> v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::HandleApiCallHelper<false>(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::BuiltinArguments<(v8::internal::BuiltinExtraArguments)1>)
 6: v8::internal::Builtin_HandleApiCall(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*)
 7: 0x14a2e930961b
 8: 0x14a2e95935a4
```

I understand that this won't be a breaking change until the next release, but does anyone know what package this is coming from and where I should be looking for a fix? Also is there a way to suppress this?

Comment: Yeah, got the same thing with node-sass here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Issues have been open over various projects (including nodejs) and some PRs have already been submitted; e.g.

- [strongloop/fsevents #127](https://github.com/strongloop/fsevents/issues/127), Using deprecated APIs in node v6
- [nodejs/citgm #124](https://github.com/nodejs/citgm/issues/124), List of modules broken by node v6
- [nodejs/node #6277](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/6277), v8: warn in Template::Set() on improper use.

We may just have to wait for v6.0.1.

Comment: Awesome thanks. I searched the node github repo but obviously not hard enough. Not a huge deal. Just makes my test output look ugly

Comment: Here's another one to add to the list: https://github.com/tugrul/node-mcrypt/issues/54

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error in some projects, and I solved all of them, updating dependencies.

I know that probably you will  not agree to update all dependencies in some circurstances, so you can edit the packake.json file, and change one by one each dependency to "latest".

And then execute **npm install** to update all dependencies to the latest release

for instance, this is my package.json of one of my projects:

`"dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "latest",
    "eris-contracts": "latest",
    "express": "latest",
    "mongodb": "latest",
    "promise": "latest",
    "rootpath": "latest"
  }`